# How can I write 'If p then q' to calculate a truth table?

Tags: python

> Write a Python program that produces a truth table for the following statements:
>
> - p and q
> - p or q
> - if p, then q
> - p if and only if q
>
> To earn credit, you must calculate the truth values.

I was able to use:

```
print(getSym(p), getSym(q), getSym(p and q), getSym(p or q),
```

to figure out the 'and' and the 'or' statements

```
def getSym(x):
    if x:
        return 'T'
    else:
        return 'F'

values = [True, False]

print('and')
for p in values:
    for q in values:
        print(getSym(p), getSym(q), getSym(p and q), getSym(p or q), getSym())
```

I have gotten the first two statements to output a correct truth table

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the and/or equivalents

```
p -> q  is not p or q
p iff q is p == q
```

Can you take it from there?